# How to delete multiple rows with 2 columns as composite primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

For example we have the following query that works in Oracle, however, it does not work in SQL Server. How can we rewrite it for SQL server?

```
delete from cpi
where (countryid, year) in (('AD', 2010), ('AF', 2009), ('AG', 1992))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a lot more clunky in comparison, but you can use a [table value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to create your list of tuples within an `EXISTS` clause and match it that way, e.g.

```
DELETE FROM cpi
WHERE EXISTS 
      ( SELECT  1
        FROM (VALUES ('AD', 2010), ('AF', 2009), ('AG', 1992)) AS v (countryid, year)
        WHERE v.countryid = cpi.countryid
        AND v.year = cpi.year
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are really only a few pairs, just:

```
 delete from cpi
 where (countryid = 'AD' and year = 2010) or (countryid = 'AF' and year = 2009) or (countryid = 'AG' and year = 1992)
```

Or, if there are more, maybe something like:

```
 delete from cpi
 where countryid + '|' + convert(varchar(4),year) in ('AD|2010','AF|2009','AG|1992')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can express this using a table-value constructor . . . in the `delete`:

```
delete from cpi
    from (values ('AD', 2010), ('AF', 2009), ('AG', 1992) ) v(countryid, year)
    where cpi.countryid = v.countryid and cpi.year = cpi.year;
```

No subquery is needed.